# Passing "part" of a function pointer as an argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, lambda, function-pointers

I'm sure this has been asked before, but it's just hard to search for...
So, what I've got is a function that accepts a function pointer. This function pointer has, say, 3 arguments. So, I want to pass to another function, the same pointer, but with 2 arguments filled in.

So, something like this:

```
int func1 (int (*funcptr)(int, int, int)) {
  return func2(funcptr(,8,9));
}

int func2 (int (*funcptr)(int)) {
  return (*funcptr)(2);
}
```

EDIT:
 Ok so I got this now with the usage of a lambda

```
int func2(int (*funcptr2)(int)) {
  return (*funcptr2)(2);
}
int func1(int (*funcptr1)(int, int, int)) {
  return func2(
    [funcptr1](int i)->int {
      return (*funcptr1)(i,8,9);
    }
  );
}
```

But it's giving me

"cannot convert `func1(int (*)(int, int, int))::<lambda(int)>` to `int (*)(int)` for argument 1 to `int func2(int (*)(int))`"

Comment: See `std::bind` (it's also in `boost`)

Comment: See the "perfect forwarding" too (you can google it). C++11 standard has enabled perfect forwarding exactly for you cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question, a lambda which captures variables (as your lambda does with `funcptr1`) cannot be converted to a function pointer. Intuitively this makes sense since your lambda must store this captured variable per lambda; whereas there is no way to do that with a function pointer.

The best solution is probably to take an argument of type `std::function`, which is a wrapper for any callable type:

```
int func2(std::function<int(int)> funcptr2) {
  return funcptr2(2);
}
int func1(std::function<int(int,int,int)> funcptr1) {
  return func2(
    [funcptr1](int i)->int {
      return funcptr1(i,8,9);
    }
  );
}
```

You can also use templates to make your functions work for any callable type:

```
template <typename F>
int func2(F funcptr2) {
  return funcptr2(2);
}
template <typename F>
int func1(F funcptr1) {
  return func2(
    [funcptr1](int i)->int {
      return funcptr1(i,8,9);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a lambda, and you can do it with [newer C++ versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Lambda_functions_and_expressions), std::bind, boost::bind or [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/function.html).

Comment: A lambda (i.e, inline function definition) is one way of implementing this task. This task, however, is specifically known as a "partial application" of a function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application

Comment: So, would I do something like `return func2([](int x){funcptr(x,8,9);})`

Comment: @duskwuff: I've used the term more generally (to include partial application and similar generic function generation mechanisms), but I think my usage is incorrect, at least in the C++ world.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use a lambda. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can't.  You would have to pass the function pointer, and the two arguments.

In C++, you can use `std::bind` (or `boost::bind` in older versions) to achieve this.